# Drop down live update in a form

Tags: php

How do you live update the content of drop down 2 based on the selection made in drop down 1 in a PHP based web form?

Would appreciate any code examples to work from.

Many thanks!

Comment: if you don't want to submit the form after select 1 you don't do it with php, as its server side, you want something client side like javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to use AJAX, I would recommend jQuery's abstraction.

e.g.

```
<select id="sel1">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select id="sel2">
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#sel1').change(funciton(){
   $.ajax({url: 'fetchSel2.php',
           data:{sel1:$('#sel1').val()},
           success:function(data){
               $('#sel2').html(data);
           }
          });
});
</script>
```

This presumes there is a 'fetchSel2.php' that is ready to serve the options for the second select.

e.g.

```
function getSecondOptions($sel1){
    $r=mysql_query(RELEVANT_QUERY);
    $opts='';
    if($r && mysql_num_rows($r)>0){
        while(list($label,$val)=mysql_fetch_row($r)){
            $opts.='<option value="'.$val.'">'.$label.'</option>';
        }
    }
    return $opts;
}

if(isset($_GET['sel1'])){
    echo getSecondOptions($_GET['sel1']);
}
exit;
```

Comment: Could you show me an example of the code that would abide in the "fetchSel2.php" file based on the option made in the sel1?

Comment: I am trying to incorporate this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493272/setting-up-a-live-refresh-on-select-drop-down

Comment: @jeansymolanza Example added =)

Answer (score 1):

For live update, you need to use AJAX and require JS enabled browser. If the user-browser don't support JS or JS is disabled, the only option is to submit the form and reload the whole page with the updated option in the 2nd dropdown. If you want the JS code to perform AJAX, can you kindly tell me the JS library you want to use, so I can provide the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a cascading dropdown list. This is done using AJAX triggered in sequence by each dropdown. Here is an example via Google (http://codestips.com/php-ajax-cascading-dropdown-using-mysql/), note I'm not endorsing this link, it's just the first reasonable result.

Answer (score 1):

I recently did this with jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/tBrXt/1/

Comment: How can I go about incorporating this into it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493272/setting-up-a-live-refresh-on-select-drop-down

Comment: @jeansymolanza check the answers to that.

Answer (score 1):

You have these options:

- Use AJAX if you don't want the form to refresh and update parts of
  the form.
- If you don't want to use ajax and can bear with refreshing the whole
  form, you can capture the `onChange` event of the drop down using
  javascript.
- If the user does not have javascript enabled, the above 2 methods
  will fail. Therefore, it is best to include a button users can click,
  which will ask the PHP side to rerender the form.

My personal preference is to use the last method as a fall back for those who do not have javascript enabled. Then use the first method (AJAX) to progressively enhance the form for those that have javascript.