# How to format a drop down list to use only selected answers depending on first dropdown

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

http://whodateswhere.com/auto/
This is my site I'm building.
Where it shows:
Make:
Model:
I'd like to know, after the first is chosen, how do I let the second drop down know it will be from that make?

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $.get('makes_models.php', function(data){
       $('#ajax_make_select').html( data ); 
    });

    // on change of dropdown1 populate dropdown2 with the respective data 
    $('#ajax_make_select').change(function(){
        $.get('models.php',{ make: $('ajax_make_select').val() }, function(data){
            $('#ajax_model_select').html( data ); 
        }); 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

with the makes_models.php code is:

```
<select>
<option value=999>Select a Make</option>
<option value=1>Acura</option>
<option value=2>Audi</option>
<option value=3>BMW</option>
</select>
```

How would I go about coding the second file? "models.php"

 if Acura is chosen, I would like it to display

```
<option value=1>MDX</option>
<option value=2>RDX</option>
<option value=3>RL</option>
<option value=4>TL</option>
<option value=5>TSX</option>
<option value=6>ZDX</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493272/setting-up-a-live-refresh-on-select-drop-down/7493296#7493296).

http://jsfiddle.net/tBrXt/2/

In response to how you would code the second file, use the [`switch/case`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement:

```
<?php
    switch($_GET['make']) {
        case "acura":
            echo json_encode(array("MDX","RDX","RL","TL","TSX","ZDX"));
            return;
        case "ford":
            echo json_encode(array('f150','mustang','etc'));
            return;
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Hey Korvin, I've been told json is the most efficient way to do this. I didn't really understand how to do it until you showed me. Thanks!
I wish I understood this all more, still having trouble getting it together but hopefully soon

Comment: `JSON` is `JavaScript Object Notation`, it's a string that contains the contents of a `JavaScript Object`. Both `PHP` and `JavaScript` have the ability to `natively parse` this string into it's respective object (Array is an option in `PHP`), this makes it easy to communicate between the two.