# How to get every state or province in the world based on Country using PHP?

Tags: php

I am requiring users who register on my site to specify their location. For this I have 2 selects:

```
Country

State/Province
```

I found snippets online that list every country in a select option format. But how can I populate the State/Province dropdown based on what the user selected in the 1st country dropdown?

I know I have to do it through AJAX, but I am referring to the data itself. What can I use to determine all the states/provinces for each country in the world?

And what would be an example of the implementation please.

Comment: You could open an atlas and type up the list yourself... Either way, offtopic, since you just want the Geo data, and not actual programming help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has been answered many times:

Check out my answers

[How to format a drop down list to use only selected answers depending on first dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800197/how-to-format-a-drop-down-list-to-use-only-selected-answers-depending-on-first-d/7800245#7800245)

[Setting up a live refresh on select drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493272/setting-up-a-live-refresh-on-select-drop-down/7493296#7493296)

Comment: Sorry, changed my title. I already know how to do the actual dropdown change part. I was asking about the data.

Comment: You've got to set up a multidimensional array of all the data you'd like to display. It's been my experience that there are no lists out there for free, but it's rather easy to compile a list of states/countries.